# How can I move file after Apache Camel Batch processing?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-batch

I bring a file from Amazon S3 and process it with Spring Batch, all integrated with Apache Camel.

After the batch, message body is not the file content anymore, it's de Job. But I want to move the file to another s3 bucket.  How can I get the File content back? (I do have the headers)

*(Using S3 is circumstantial)*

```
        from("aws-s3://my-bucket...")
            .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelAwsS3Key"),
                  MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository(200))
            .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key}"))
            .to("file:my-files/")
            .log("Copied from S3.")
            .to("spring-batch:historicoJob")
            .choice()
            .when(simple("${in.body.status} == 'COMPLETED'"))
            .to("direct:moveIt")
            .endChoice();

    from("direct:moveIt")
             ...
            .to("aws-s3://done-bucket...");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to the original message (there is some api on camel exchange -> unit of work), or you can copy the message body to an exchange property before the spring batch, and then restore it again afterwards.